# JSF components are not rendered

Tags: jsf

I am a newbie in Java EE and i'm following the official java ee's pdf documentation from oracle.
I'm facing some problems because of the complexity of the documentation.
My problem actually is when I'm running a .jsf page it doesn't show the form( inputs and submit button)
but it show all the other things...

```
<html lang="en"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
<h:head>Bienvenue</h:head>
<h:body>
<h:form>
<p>test</p>
<h:inputText id="username" title="My name is: " value="coucou" required="true" maxlength="25" />
<h:commandButton id="submit" value="Submit" action="response"/>
</h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

P.S: I am using NetBeans 8.

Comment: Make sure you're using JSF 2.2 and that you're using the right URL pattern for your application. It would be better if you provide the content of web.xml file and the exact URL you're using to access to your view.

Comment: You initially tagged JSF-2. This namespace `http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html` is a JSF 2.2 thing (the preceding comment indicates such). If you insist upon using that version, the namespace should be `http://java.sun.com/jsf/html`.